# How can I get this div to scale with the window size

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Complete noob and working on a project for school.  I have a div with a nested div with 2 images.  My main goal is when the image is hovered over, the other image changes its opacity and shows.  However, I am told that divs cannot scale with the window size.  Anyway, I can change my code or add something to make this happen?  I added a segment of the CSS code and halfways through is the index.html code.

```css
.container-inner {
  position: relative;
}

.ball-container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 65%;
  bottom: 18%;
}

.ball-container .label {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-20%, -75%) scale(.7);
  opacity: 0;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: .3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.ball-container .ball-img {
  position: absolute;
  transform: scale(.8);
}

.ball-container:hover .label {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="top-container" class="top-container">
  <img class="bkg-img" src="images/top_container/sceneBkg.png" alt="Landscape">
  <img id="large-cloud1" class="large-cloud" src="images/top_container/cloud1.png" alt="cloud">
  <img id="large-cloud2" class="large-cloud" src="images/top_container/cloud1.png" alt="cloud">
  <img id="large-cloud3" class="large-cloud" src="images/top_container/cloud1.png" alt="cloud">
  <img id="small-cloud1" class="small-cloud" src="images/top_container/cloud1.png" alt="cloud">
  <img id="small-cloud2" class="small-cloud" src="images/top_container/cloud1.png" alt="cloud">

  <img class="southpaw-body-img" src="images/top_container/southpaw_body.png" alt="head">
  <img class="southpaw-head-img" src="images/top_container/southpaw_head.png" alt="body">

  <img class="doghouse-label" src="images/top_container/doghouse_label.png" alt="doghouse label">
  <img class="doghouse-img" src="images/top_container/doghouse.png" alt="doghouse">


  <div class="book-container">
    <div class="container-inner">
      <img class="label" src="images/top_container/book_label.png" alt="book label">
      <img class="book-img" src="images/top_container/bookStack.png" alt="book stack">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="banner-container">
    <div class="container-inner">
      <img class="label" src="images/top_container/banner_label.png" alt="banner label">
      <img class="banner-img" src="images/top_container/banner.png" alt="banner">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="ball-container">
    <div class="container-inner">
      <img class="label" src="images/top_container/ball_label.png" alt="ball label">
      <img class="ball-img" src="images/top_container/ball.png" alt="ball">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="weight-container">
    <div class="container-inner">
      <img class="label" src="images/top_container/weight_label.png" alt="weight label">
      <img class="weight-img" src="images/top_container/weight.png" alt="weight">
    </div>
  </div>

  <img class="logo-img" src="images/top_container/logo.png" alt="body">
</div>
```

Comment: To use percentages just remember that it's based on your parent Element, so 100% is 100% of the parent, not the screen.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to wrap my head around this.  The top container is a div with a display of relative which is obviously inside the body.  I have a div of absolute that holds another div to keep both img elements relative.  They are absolute.  The div container that is absolute is referencing the top_container div.  However, the size is not changing as the top-container div is.  But chaning the width and heigh properties in the div container, it does not change anything.

Comment: Ok...I think I figured it out.  After adding the correct percentages withing the image, I then corrected the proper percentages in the parent div and it is scaling correctly.  I also added height: auto to each block.   Thanks for getting me through this!